# How can I add a column to a Spark DataFrame containing aggregations like mean and count?

Tags: dataframe, group-by, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my code:

```
DF = DF.withColumn("MAX",DF.groupBy("NUM_TIERS").max())
```

It gave me the following error:

> AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)  in
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in
>   withColumn(self, colName, col)    1986     1987         """
>   -> 1988         assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"    1989         return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc),
>   self.sql_ctx)    1990
>
> AssertionError: col should be Column

[image]

Comment: Do you want to insert the maxes for those columns back into the original dataframe?

Comment: you can join with the new Dataframe having aggregations

Comment: yes i want to insert the maxes for those columns back into the original dataframe

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBoho.png . Please look at this @AkhilBatra

Answer (score 0):

I will not understand your question in the manner, but according to what I understood, it is, please check It.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
DF=DF.withColumn("MAX",lit(DF.groupBy("NUM_TIERS").max().count()))
```

Comment: thank you @Anuj . your answer was helpful but i dont want to get .max().count() .

Comment: please take a look on this Image :